# Protecting protected and/or private value from Symfony VarDumper

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I'm trying to hide all the class variable from Symfony's dumper `dd`,

```
App\Namespace\Class1 {#NNN ▼
  -requestCollection: []
  -requestDumpOptions: []
  -responseCacheTime: -1
  -responseCode: -1
  -responseData: ""
  -responseRawData: ""
}
```

I was tried to use class magic method `__debugInfo` but it append the dump object instead of replacing it

Code :

```
...
    public function __debugInfo()
    {
        return ['copyright' => 'SOME COPYRIGHT'];
    }
...
```

Result :

```
App\Namespace\Class1 {#NNN ▼
  -requestCollection: []
  -requestDumpOptions: []
  -responseCacheTime: -1
  -responseCode: -1
  -responseData: ""
  -responseRawData: ""
  copyright: "SOME COPYRIGHT"
}
```

My goal is to only show `copyrigth` field in the dump

```
App\Namespace\Class1 {#NNN ▼
  copyright: "SOME COPYRIGHT"
}
```

Using dump again on `__debugInfo` works but it return `Array` instance instead of `App\Namespace\Class1`

```
...
    public function __debugInfo()
    {
        dd(['copyright' => 'SOME COPYRIGHT']);
    }
...
```

Comment: so basically you want that the global function dd() cannot access your private & protected function?

Comment: yeah, I want to hide it from `dd()`

Comment: I think var dumper cannot do that

Comment: But why?  If you don't want to expose info via dd then don't use dd.  In fact, you should not even have the component installed in production.

Comment: @Cerad I will sell the source code to Other,  and I was planning to Obfuscate the source code using IonCube and make a license to the source code, I had to do it because it can transfer money directly, the private variable had a sensitive data, I want to prevent hackers / buyer known the library algorithm if they has access to the class

Comment: You do understand that if someone could add a dump statement to your code then they can use reflection to access the same data?  Embedding sensitive data into source code is just asking for trouble.  I'd suggest consulting a security expert.

Comment: Are they still can use reflection in obfuscated source code?

Answer (score 2):

I found your question interesting & tried a way out, if I am correct you don't want to allow `dd()` to access you private & protected properties.

For that I have created a custom function in my `app/helpers.php`,
I named it `mydd()`, this is how it looks,

```
if (! function_exists('mydd') ){
    function mydd($obj=null, ...$args){
        foreach($args as $arg){
            if(isset($obj) && is_object($obj)){
                $reflect = new ReflectionObject($obj);
                if(in_array($reflect->getProperty($arg), $reflect->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PRIVATE | ReflectionProperty::IS_PROTECTED))){
                    throw new RuntimeException("Cannot access private or protected properties");
                }
            }
            \Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper::dump($arg);
        }

        die(1);
    }
}
```

It will do your work, but there are certain changes from `dd()`, you need to pass the object along with the property, if not then pass `null` as first argument to the function `mydd()`, because I guess there is nothing that can find object instance of a class from its property.
I have used [Reflection Class](https://www.php.net/reflection) Object for that. So basically it will check if the given property of the same object passed as first argument is either private or protected & throw runtime exception.

### My Testing

Created a class called DDRepository,

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

class DDRepository{

    private $foo = 'foo';
    public $bar = 'bar';
    private $shoo = 'shoo';
    protected $too = 'too';

    public function __construct(){

    }

    public function getFoo(){
        mydd($this,$this->too);
    }
}
```

Then called it from web.php

```
Route::get('checkdd', function(){
    $ddrepo = new \App\Repository\DDRepository;
    $ddrepo->getFoo();
});
```

throws Exception as shown in pic,
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but It seems doesn't fit with my goal, I want to preventing other dump my `Class1` private variable because it has a sensitive information on it, by using your method, I cant tell other to use `mydd` instead of `dd`

Comment: You can edit your dd() function, actually I don't know where your dd function is located, I searched for the dd() function in two projects first one in lumen, I found it in `Illuminate\support\helpers.php`, then I tried it in laravel 6 but there was no such function in above path, I found dd() in some other class file of Illuminate called Enumerate.php, so you have to do a GLOBAL SEARCH AND FIND THE `dd()` in your project then put lines inside `if(isset($obj) && is_object($obj)){` in your dd() then it will work, you also have to make some efforts

Comment: If I edit the `dd` function, Other can copy my `Class1` and try to run it on new Laravel project, and Other can simply use `composer update` to update the vendor component (symfony/var-dumper)

Comment: Then you can comment that dd() or search for something that can give preference to your dd() made in app/helpers instead of illuminate/helpers function dd(), `if (! function_exists('dd') ){` this will check if dd function exists but I can't be sure which one will be accessed first

Comment: Yeah, but even If I can do that, I still cant replace the original `var_dump`

Comment: haha :)  you can do that as well, just take original code of php from github do your edits for var_dump() then build your php in the system but are you ready to take that much effort, wouldn't it be better to use a .env hidden file to hide your values

Comment: Using .env for sensitive value will probably make a chaos, other just can take a look of it

Answer (score -2):

I have understood your concern. First of all, let me discuss about the variable scope private. private variable is private in the current class. If you use the class in another class private variable will not work. So, you have to use another class to protect your private variable.

```
<?php

class ParentClass 
{
    private $yourPrivateVariable = "yourPrivateVariable";
}

class Class1 extends ParentClass 
{
    private $username = "api";
    public function doSomething(){   
    // write code using private variable
   }

}


class NewClass
{   
    public function doSomething()

    {
       $test = new Class1();
       $test -> doSomething();
       return $this->public = "Joe";
    }
}


$test = new NewClass();
$test->doSomething();
var_dump($test);

//output
//object(NewClass)#1 (1) {
//  ["public"]=>
//  string(3) "Joe"
//}


?>
```

now you can see that non of private variables are showing in result.

Comment: I was creating `Class1` to extend `ParentClass` which has the private variable, and if I dump `new MyClassProtected()` the private variable still visible to the `dump` function

Comment: i update my answer. test it and tell me results. @Illya

Comment: I dumped `new ParentClass()` and still printed the private variable

Comment: you must use  ```NewClass``` instead not ```ParentClass``` actually there is no way to prevent dumper from dumping parameters as i mentioned but there is a trick that i mentioned in answer to hide ```ParentClass``` and use ```NewClass``` the ```NewClass``` act's like ```ParentClass``` with this difference that no one can see  ```ParentClass``` private parameters any more